# How to make `tty` work in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, tty, gpg

I have the following in my `~/.bash_profile` in order to try to make GPG work nicely:

```
export GPG_TTY="`tty`"
```

But when I open a new shell, I get the following:

```
$ echo $GPG_TTY
not a tty
```

However, if I then `source ~/.bash_profile` again it then works and contains something like `/dev/pts/2`.

Is there a way to make this work automatically when the shell is opened? Could it be that sourcing that file initially is done before the tty is allocated and, if so, is there a way of doing it later?

Comment: Does it work better if you have it in your `~/.bashrc` file? This file is supposed to be sourced for interactive shells while the profile file is used for login shells (and I don't know when such a shell is launched on your system).

Comment: I cannot reproduce you problem -- you probably have something else in your start-up scripts that's causing it (some temporary stdin redirection?)

Comment: @mosvy It may be that their interactive shells are inheriting the environment of a _non-interactive_ login shell (which is not connected to a TTY).  I presume this would be possible with some sort of graphical desktop setup.

Comment: Another idea would be to configure your terminal emulator to always spawn a login shell rather than a interactive non-login shell.  But really, since the `GPG_TTY` needs to be _different_ for each interactive shell, the easiest solution would probably be just to move the setting of this variable to `~/.bashrc`.  Not writing this as an answer since I don't know anything about how the shells are spawned on the user's machine.

Comment: @Kusalananda you're right, they're probably sourcing `.bash_profile` from `.xsession` or `/etc/X11/Xsession*` (I have the feeling that that's not a default setup anywhere -- it was probably taken from an answer from here ;-)). Anyways, they're probably better off by an `alias gpg='GPG_TTY=\`tty\` gpg'` instead of polluting the enviroment.

Comment: Thanks, yes, putting it in `~/.bashrc` does indeed fix it. Should have tried that really :) Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `GPG_TTY` environment variable should hold the path to the TTY device for the current interactive shell. It would therefore make most sense to have this in one's `~/.bashrc` file rather than in the `~/.bash_profile` file, as the login shell (which parses the profile file) may in fact not be interactive under some circumstances.

Therefore, remove the setting of `GPG_TTY` from `~/.bash_profile` and instead add it as

```
export GPG_TTY="$( tty )"
```

in your `~/.bashrc` file.

In general, add session specific setup of interactive shells in `~/.bashrc` and setup that is not session specific to the `~/.bash_profile` file.